# Fade image onload but not for cache

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, preload

I want to fade-in images on my page when they load, but if this image is not already in cache - just show it normally.
I've tried inline html

```
<img onload="$(this).show(500)" />
```

and css img{display:none}, but it fires even if this image is already in cache.
How do I fade-in only images, which are not in cache?

Comment: What about jQuery? `$("#element-id").fadeIn(time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in all relevant browsers.

On domready, the cached image will be `complete` already, thus the `onload` handler is not set.

```
$('img.fadeuncached').each(function() {
    if(!this.complete) {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.load(function() { $el.fadeIn(500); });
    }
});
```

Comment: if(!this.complete) is what I needed! Thx!