# Triggering a CSS img animation only if the image is not cached

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

The picture of myself on my [website](https://christopherkade.com/) is loaded with a blur animation that I enjoy like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="christopher-img" style="background:url(../../assets/img/chris.jpg)"></div>
```

SASS:

```
.christopher-img 
    width: 200px
    height: 200px
    border-radius: 50%
    margin: 0 auto
    background-color: white
    filter: blur(3px)
    animation: unblur 1s
    animation-delay: 1s
    animation-fill-mode: forwards

.christopher-img::after
    animation: low-quality 1s
    animation-delay: 1s

@keyframes low-quality
    0% 
        background-image: url(../../assets/img/chris_low_quality.jpg)

@keyframes unblur
    100% 
        filter: blur(0px)
```

But the animation is triggered every time the home page is accessed, and I wish to change that.

How may I trigger an animation under certain conditions? And how may I know if the image is already cached by the user?

Comment: Could use javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755933/fade-image-onload-but-not-for-cache

Comment: Just create a separate class with the blur effect, then set up a cookie when the user loads the page for the first time, if the cookie exists, remove the class that adds the blur.

Answer (score 0):

The answer requires several steps:

1. Extract animation into separate class, e. g. `.uncached`
2. If [`resource.transferSize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize) is zero then add `.uncached` class to the image

Your JS should be exactly below image in your HTML for the best results.

### Here is an example (works in Chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/cevL65py/2/

Check the console for API and cache assertions.

This is the most important part:

```
const imageData = performance.getEntriesByName(url)
const isUncached = imageData.length > 0 ? imageData[0].transferSize !== 0 : true
```